# Photoshop Action Script Needed to change a text several times and save as a JPG

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Photoshop Action Script Needed to change a text in a layer from number 0 to 250 and save it as a JPG file format.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll find you'll get answers faster if you supply any code you've used (and tried) to solve your problem.

The code you need is quite simple. You could have searched SO for save as Jpg code, it's quite common. 
Changing the text code is simple it's a case of making a reference to the text contents and checking to see if it's "0" and then changing it to "255".

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var changedText = change_text("0", "255");
// function returns true if the text is changed
if (changedText) saveAsJpg("c:\\temp\\myfile.jpg", 12)


function change_text(textfrom, textto)
{
  // check tosee if layer is text
  if (app.activeDocument.activeLayer.kind == "LayerKind.TEXT")
  {
    var textRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem;
    var textContents = textRef.contents;

    // if the text is what we are looking for

    if (textContents== textfrom)
    {    

      // ...change the text contents
      textRef.contents = textto;
      return true;
    } 
  }
}

// save as a jpg
function saveAsJpg(filePath, myJpgQuality)
{
  // Flatten the jpg
  activeDocument.flatten();

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```